# Build lagrangian from dirac field triplet and scalar triplet with $SO(3)$ symmetry

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, group-theory

I am given an exercise where I need to build the most general relativistic lagrangian from a dirac triplet $\psi^i$ and scalar triplet $\phi^i$ invariant under $SO(3)$ (up to terms order $d<5$).

I already know that the answer is of the following form
$$ \mathcal{L} = 1/2 \partial_\mu \phi^i \partial^\mu \phi^i - M^2/2 \phi^i \phi^i + i \bar{\psi}^i \partial \psi^i - m \bar{\psi^i} \psi^i + ig e_{ijk} \bar{\psi^i} \psi^j \phi^k + \lambda/4 (\phi^i \phi^i)(\phi^j \phi^j).$$

Globally I understood most of the construction. I understood that in order to be invariant lagrangian under $SO(3)$ we have to contract the indexes $i$ and $j$ to bring the tensor product between triplet product into the trivial representation. However the way it really happens is quite unclear for me. I am kind of doing it as habit and because I know those kind of conventions. For the case with only two terms it seems to be the only choice. However when we have three terms product I can't see why we must necessarily contract them with the levi-civita tensor. I'd like to know what's the reason behind this choice. Moreover I can't see why we don't find terms as $$e_{ijk} \phi^i \phi^j \phi^k.$$

But the answer is probably related to my first question I guess. If you could help me having a better comprehension of what's really happening behind there on group theory point of view I would very much appreciate.

Comment: The trilinear scalar term you wrote vanishes: it is the antisymmetrization of three symmetric scalars. By contrast, the Yukawa term of the answer has no reason to vanish.  To see the invariance of the Yukawa term, make an infinitesimal so(3) transformation of that term and observe how the variation vanishes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ha yeah indeed I was a bit dumb on this one, and yeah I see why it is invariant. And about the levi-civita tensor, why do we always use this one to build higher terms couldn't we use other tensors ?

Comment: Assuming $\psi$ is a Dirac fields, then you can't have a term with three $\psi$'s in it.

Comment: Hi, I don't feel like it answers my question. I already noticed your point.

Comment: The Levi-Civita tensor is the only antisymmetric tensor left invariant by a rotation. It is the Riemann volume form.

Comment: Oh i see does it also applies for so(N) as well as su(N) ? Or at least su(2) ?

Comment: I don't know whom you are replying to, but regardless of what global symmetry you are considering, triple Dirac field term is not allowed.

Comment: Côme Zachos my question is probably once again a bit stupid but why does it necessarely has to be antisymmetric ?

Comment: It applies to SO(N) and SU(N). There are symmetric ones for SU(3), etc... Hamermesh's book has nice explanations...